# Media query stopped working

Tags: html, css, media

I've been playing around with the idea of an adaptive website and for some time everything was adapting. And I just moved on and lived *happily ever after*. Until my media query stopped working.

These are my columns. I don't know why, but they don't work anymore.

```
<p class="left">
    Content             
</p>

<p class="middle">
    More content
</p>

<p class="right">
    Even more content
</p>
```

And this is the CSS that is **supposed** to make my three columns into 
one column if the screen gets too small.

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {

    .left, .middle, .right, {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

}
```

And here's the CSS for when my columns are separate:

```
.left, .middle, .right {
    float: left;
    width: 170px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

I've been pulling my hair out for the last hour and I have checked and this is how it's been in the earlier versions of my code. And in **those** versions, everything *just works*!

Comment: @media screen and (max-width: 500px)?

Comment: Remove the comma after `.right,` in `(max-width: 500px)` media query. You have a typo error in your syntax.

Comment: It's because the CSS property expects more selectors after comma and there are none. Not a very good explanation, but hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

First put the normal css statements and then the media query statement.
Thus:
before

```
.left, .middle, .right {
    float: left;
    width: 170px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

after

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {

    .left, .middle, .right {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

}
```